# magento sample data

Tags: version, versioning

I have three magento sample data files.  Are these safe to use **ONLY** on identical versions and up?

ie:  magento-sample-data-1.6.1.0  is only good for vrs 1.6.1.0CE and up?  I tried installing this on vrs 1.6.0.0CE and it appears to work just fine.  However, I'm not sure about any inconsistencies that might be hidden that I just don't see right away

I also have magento-enterprise-sample-data-1.11.1.0 and magento-enterprise-sample-data-1.3.0

I have about 16 versions that I need to have setup for regression testing for plugins.

the versions highlighted in bold are specifically the ones that I'm concerned with. Are there best practices about handling this situation?

- **mage-1-6-0-0.site.net**
- mage-1-6-1-0.site.net
- mage-1-6-2-0.site.net
- mage-1-7-0-0.site.net
- mage-1-7-0-1.site.net
- mage-1-7-0-2.site.net
- **mage-1-9-1-1.site.net**
- **mage-1-10-0-2.site.net**
- **mage-1-10-1-1.site.net**
- **mage-1-11-0-0.site.net**
- **mage-1-11-0-2.site.net**
- mage-1-11-1-0.site.net
- mage-1-11-2-0.site.net
- mage-1-12-0-0.site.net
- mage-1-12-0-1.site.net
- mage-1-12-0-2.site.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For CE versions 1.6.1.0+ the sample data should work without any problems, and for EE versions 1.11.0.2+.

For versions lower than that I used the sample data for 1.1.2 [that can be found here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/download) in the release archive tab.

But there is a catch.
For CE version 1.6.0.0 you need to install first 1.5 over the sample database and after that install 1.6.0.0 over the db that results from the installation of 1.5.
For CE version 1.5.x and lower the sample data for 1.1.2 works great.

Unfortunately I have no idea of the EE versions and sample data. But you can try to use the sample data from CE for EE.

I think EE 1.9.1.1 corresponds to CE 1.4.x - so you can use the sample for 1.1.2
And I'm sure that EE 1.12x corresponds to CE 1.7.x so you can  use the sample for 1.6

Following the pattern i can conclude that EE 1.10 = CE 1.5 and EE 1.11 = CE 1.6 but I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't even aware there were more than 2 versions of Sample data, pre 1.6.1.0 and post.

We use our [install script](http://www.sonassi.com/knowledge-base/fully-automated-magento-install-script/) for CE which decides the appropriate version of sample data to use for whichever version of Magento you are installing.

EE 1.12 = CE 1.7 *(and so on)*

So for EE 1.11.1.0, CE 1.6.1.0 and higher - you need to use the new sample data

```
$magento_assets_url/$sample_data_version/magento-sample-data-$sample_data_version.tar.gz
```

Where

```
sample_data_version='1.6.1.0'
  or
sample_data_version='1.2.0'
```

And

```
magento_assets_url="http://www.magentocommerce.com/downloads/assets"
```